# C# Open Byte Array in Default Mail Application

Tags: c#, arrays, outlook

I have an application that will save items in the DB as a blob. Users have been using it to save emails (.msg files).

The app also allows users to view uploaded files. The app gets the file as a byte array and displays it.

However it is failing when trying to open .msg files.

It used to work using the following:

```
Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

However that has stopped working recently and now just downloads the file to their PC instead of opening it.

I have tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(imageModel.imageString); // the string that gets converted to a byte array
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But I get an error saying the string is too long.

Does anyone know how I can open a byte array in the default email application? It will be outlook for these uers. I'd prefer to not first save it as a file on their PC and send the byte array directly to outlook.

Comment: Did they recently update/upgrade their Office Suite?

Comment: @Fildor I think so. I'm not actually privy to what updates happen and when, but something changed recently that caused this to no longer work. Either outlook or chrome changes.

Comment: So you send the data from a web server? Do you correctly set the content type and the file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I used for this it to simple have the app download the .msg file to the users comoputer, then open in the default mail app.

I was not able to get it to open in Outlook from a byte array.